# Where should the cleat be on the shoe?

Tags: pedals, shoes, clipless, spd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an optimal postion for SPD cleats?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/is-there-an-optimal-postion-for-spd-cleats)

SPD cleats (and others) can be positioned on the shoe over a range of about an inch, forward or backward. Where do most people position it? What are the advantages and disadvantages of putting it near the toe, back toward the center of the foot, or half way in between?

Comment: I agree, this looks like a duplicate. However, I'm not a clipless user; if there's something subtle here that I'm missing, we can edit and re-open.

Comment: I agree it's a duplicate. I looked for a dup, but the search didn't find it. I'll search harder next time.

Comment: Don't worry about it too much. I see @freiheit updated the tags on the older question; it'll now be a little easier to find.